# API Server always response " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, cors, laravel-5.4, ionic3

I write back-end with laravel. And try to call api from IONIC use `@angular/http`.

In back-end serer, I already add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in middleware and response.

Middleware.

```
return $next($request)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
      ->header('Vary', 'Origin');
```

Response.

```
return response($data, 200)
      ->withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type',
        'Vary' => 'Origin',
      ]);
```

IONIC

```
  url: any = 'http://myurl.local/api/';

  headers = new Headers(
  {
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Request-Methods' : 'POST'
  });
  options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

login(username, password) {
    let data = JSON.stringify({
      username : username,
      password : password
    });
    let fullUrl = this.url+'login';

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(fullUrl, data, this.options)
      .toPromise()
      .then((response) =>
      {
        console.log('API Response : ', response);
        resolve(response.json());
      })
      .catch((error) =>
      {
        console.error('API Error : ', error.toString());
        reject(error.json());
      });
    });
  }
```

When I call api with `'Content-Type' : 'application/json'` it always response error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl.local/api/login. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

But if I change `'Content-Type'` to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`. I didn't get any errors.

But when i try to see input `$request->all()`. Data i got is `'{"username":"XXXXXXXXXX","password":"XXXXXXXXXX"}' => NULL`.

With postman is fine. I really try a lot of way to solve this problem, But I can't.

What wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeahhhh!!! Finally, I can solve this. God damn it.

In middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
      return response(['OK'], 200)
        ->withHeaders([
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Authorization, Content-Type',
        ]);
    }

    return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type');

  }
```

In IONIC change header to.

```
headers = new Headers(
{
  'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
});
```

And it will not work until you add `options` route. (In my case, Because I am not use `Route::resource` )

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'AddHeader'], function()
{
  Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@index');
  Route::options('/login', 'LoginController@index');
});
```

PS. I have some logic in `function index()`, I try to use `__construct()`. But it not work.

Answer (score 1):

In your Laravel code that processes requests you need to add handling for `OPTIONS` requests:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type'
    ];
    return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
}
```

> When I call api with `'Content-Type' : 'application/json'` it always response error.
>
> But if I change `'Content-Type'` to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`. I didn't get any errors.

The `application/json` content-type triggers browsers to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests has more details.

> With postman is fine.

Postman can freely make cross-origin requests without restrictions. But browsers will not allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the response from a cross-origin request unless the response indicates that the server the request is sent is to is opting-in to receiving cross-origin requests.

And if your request is one that triggers browsers to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request, the server the request is sent to must be configured to respond to the `OPTIONS` request in the right way. That’s why you need to add additional handling in your Laravel code for `OPTIONS` requests.

If the server doesn’t respond to the `OPTIONS` preflight in the right way, the browser will stop there and never get around to doing the `POST` request you’re actually trying to send.

Comment: In middleware or controller?

Comment: May be i make something wrong? It got same problem.
`public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
      $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type'
      ];
      return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }
    return $next($request);
  }`

Comment: See my updated answer. Depending on how you have the rest of your middleware code, you may also need to explicitly set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the block that handles the OPTIONS request.